# Are there options other than TURN for P2P behind symmetric a NAT?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, nat, p2p

I'm trying to implement a system that allows clients to establish direct connections to each other with little to no configuration.

To my understanding a STUN server doesn't work behind a symetric NAT because the port to the peer client isn't the one the server sees.

I have an idea on how I would achieve this but I'm not sure if it's actually realistic or not. Here's what I'm thinking:

Imagine I attempt two connections

1. To server (succeeded)
2. To peer (failed)

The server would store information about pending clients and then tell each client to attempt a doomed connection to each other. From that failed connection, read the port it opened, tell that port to the server, and then continue establishing the connection. So rather than opening the connection to the server, use the server to share a source of truth between clients on how to connect to each other.

Now for the real questions

- Is this information accessible to my client machines for this method to work?
- If so is this method possible? Are there any other things that could prevent it working?
- If not are there any other methods that can achieve the same or similar results?

I'm a bit of a noob to peer to peer networking or really any custom networking implementation so please forgive me if I'm talking total nonsense...

Thanks!